# Future is not a member of scala.concurrent

Tags: scala, ubuntu, future

I'm getting the error `Future is not a member of scala.concurrent` when importing the `Future` class.

```
~/workspace/experiments $ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_151).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
<console>:7: error: Future is not a member of scala.concurrent
       import scala.concurrent.Future
              ^

scala>
```

I'm running this on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
~/workspace/experiments $ cat /etc/lsb-release                                                 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
```

Does any one know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading your Scala version should resolve it.  Doesn't appear that Future is a member of scala.concurrent in scala 2.9.2 
See
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/#scala.concurrent.package

vs. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.concurrent.package